# Why does yarn fail on a Docker in Mac, but is successful in linux?

Tags: docker, yarnpkg

I have a simple Dockerfile which works perfectly on linux but fails on Mac exclusively.

the step that fails is

```
RUN source /root/.bashrc && \
    yarn && \
    yarn build && \
    yarn global add serve
```

The complete Dockefile is (edited)

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /root
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add git g++ gcc libgcc libstdc++ linux-headers make python2 aws-cli jq && \
    apk update 

#-- Download and compile specific nodejs version required (10.16.3)
RUN wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.16.3/node-v10.16.3.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvzf node-v10.16.3.tar.gz
WORKDIR /root/node-v10.16.3/
RUN ./configure
RUN make -j4
RUN make install
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
RUN rm -rf /root/node-v10.16.3*

#-- Download and install spcific verion for yarn (1.17.3)
WORKDIR /opt
RUN wget https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v1.17.3/yarn-v1.17.3.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvzf yarn-v1.17.3.tar.gz
RUN echo export PATH="$PATH:/opt/yarn-v1.17.3/bin" > /root/.bashrc
RUN source /root/.bashrc

#-- install libsass
WORKDIR /opt
RUN git clone https://github.com/sass/sassc && cd sassc && \
    git clone https://github.com/sass/libsass && \
    SASS_LIBSASS_PATH=/opt/sassc/libsass make && \
    mv bin/sassc /usr/bin/sassc && \
    cd ../ && rm -rf /sassc

# created node-sass binary
ENV SASS_BINARY_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/build/Release/binding.node
RUN git clone --recursive https://github.com/sass/node-sass.git && \
    cd node-sass && \
    git submodule update --init --recursive && \
    npm install && \
    node scripts/build -f && \
    cd ../ && rm -rf node-sass

# add binary path of node-sass to .npmrc
RUN touch $HOME/.npmrc && echo "sass_binary_cache=${SASS_BINARY_PATH}" >> $HOME/.npmrc

ENV SKIP_SASS_BINARY_DOWNLOAD_FOR_CI true
ENV SKIP_NODE_SASS_TESTS true

RUN apk add aws-cli jq bash

#--

ARG ENV=prod

EXPOSE 80
RUN mkdir -p /opt/something
RUN whoami
WORKDIR /opt/something
COPY . /opt/something/
RUN chmod +x /opt/something/start_container.sh
RUN cat /root/.bashrc
RUN cp .env .env.production
RUN source /root/.bashrc && \
    yarn && \
    yarn build && \
    yarn global add serve

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/something/start_container.sh" ]
```

When it fails on Mac i get

```
Step 17/18 : RUN source /root/.bashrc &&     yarn &&     yarn build &&     yarn global add serve
 ---> Running in ddb97ab31a65
yarn install v1.17.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "@amcharts/amcharts4 > canvg@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "canvas@^2.1.0".
warning "@amcharts/amcharts4 > canvg@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "jsdom@^13.0.0".
warning "@amcharts/amcharts4 > canvg@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "xmldom@^0.1.27".
warning "react-final-form > ts-essentials@5.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "typescript@>=3.7.0".
warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app@5.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint-plugin-flowtype@3.x".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 63.56s.
yarn run v1.17.3
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run the following command: `yarn upgrade`
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the bundle. Error: static/js/3.9a1e52a6.chunk.js from Terser
Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at compiler.run (/opt/something/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:196:23)
    at finalCallback (/opt/something/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:257:39)
    at hooks.done.callAsync.err (/opt/something/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:273:13)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/opt/something/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/opt/something/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at onCompiled (/opt/something/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:271:21)
    at hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err (/opt/something/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:681:15)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/opt/something/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/opt/something/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at compilation.seal.err (/opt/something/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:678:31)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/opt/something/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/opt/something/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err (/opt/something/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1423:35)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/opt/something/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/opt/something/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at hooks.optimizeChunkAssets.callAsync.err (/opt/something/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1414:32)
```

(there are no connection problems with the repo it is trying to get from)

I'm really stomped by this. I'm just building on linux and that's fine, but i can't build on my local mac for dev...

Any pointers would be appreciated!

EDIT: I use the EXACT same base image on both linux and Mac, but it only fails in Mac... it's really weird.

David

Comment: Which exact command are you using to build your image ? What is the image your are building from (edit your question with your full dockerfile) ? This is a simple guess at this stage but I beleive your are using a `latest` tag on your image, not forcing the base image to be pullled, and you have a different version of that image on your linux and your mac.

Comment: @Zeitounator i use the exact same version (latest), i've removed the base and retried several times. Are you saying docker could be pulling different images base on which OS it is being pull from? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you compare the image id on each machine to make sure you are pulling/using the same one ? I didn't say anything else than you might not be using the same version. Until you update your question giving the exact command you are using to build (and to remove base between your retries of you did) there is no way for anyone to have a clue.